# What is the difference between hostname, hostname --fqdn, and hostname -A

Tags: networking, rhel, hostname

I have a machine I changed the hostname of. I changed it in `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/sysconfig/network`, and with `hostname` command. `hostname` returns the correct shortname, `hostname --fqdn` returns the expected FQDN, but `hostname -A` returns an old name. I changed the IP address of the machine to make sure it wasn't external DNS cache.

If I open python and run

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
print(socket.getfqdn())
```

Both return the old hostname/fqdn, the same as `hostname -A`

From the hostname man page it appears `--fqdn` just takes the shortname and domain and puts them together.

> Display the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name). A FQDN  consists of  a
>   short  host  name and the DNS domain name. Unless you are using bind
>   or NIS for host lookups you can change the  FQDN  and the 
>   DNS   domain  name  (which  is  part  of  the  FQDN)  in the /etc/hosts
>   file.

What is the difference between these commands and how can I better troubleshoot why the old hostname is sticking around.

Comment: How about the specific linux/unix and version identification.  There are cases where this information resides elsewhere and is setup at boot time from other configuration files.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4

Answer (score 8):

`hostname` returns the configured hostname or nodename. In practice, it can either be a short name (in most configurations) or a long name (normally the FQDN in this case). The short name is given by `hostname --short`.

`hostname --fqdn` returns the FQDN, which is `gethostbyname` on the nodename (as returned by the `uname` system call, see `uname(2)` man page).

`hostname -A` is something obscure and non-intuitive. In particular, despite its name and description ("all FQDNs"), it doesn't give the standard FQDN, by design. Thus I would say: do not use it. One reason is that it misses valid IP addresses of the machine, such as 127.0.1.1, with which the FQDN may be associated in the `/etc/hosts` file (this is currently the default under Debian and Ubuntu, for instance). Another issue with the `hostname -A` method is that the reverse resolution of an IP address doesn't necessarily give a FQDN; it can just be a short name.

Concerning your problem with python, it may be a bug there. I don't know. I suggest that you try the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use POSIX;

my $nodename = (POSIX::uname)[1];
print "Nodename: $nodename\n";

my @ghbn = gethostbyname $nodename;
print "FQDN: $ghbn[0]\n";

$ghbn[0] !~ /\./ && $ghbn[1] =~ /(\S+\.\S+)/
  and print "Fixed FQDN from aliases: $1\n";
```

Comment: So where does hostname -A get its information? I was having a problem with other software installed on the system that I couldn't fix until hostname -A showed the correct name.

Comment: ps, I tried to fix your 127.0.1.1 address to 127.0.0.1 but edits require 6 characters minimum. Maybe you can fix it.

Comment: @Rothgar `hostname -A` looks at the configured interfaces and reverse-resolves them (well, this is the information given in its man page). 127.0.1.1 is the right IP address in my answer, not 127.0.0.1. The fact that 127.0.1.1 is used for the FQDN (instead of 127.0.0.1) is one cause of the problem with `hostname -A`.

Comment: @vinc17: I don't think nodename is relative here. The main difference is `hostname -f` use `/etc/hosts`, while `hostname -A` use dns lookup. See more here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=718393

Comment: @Gnouc No, `hostname -A` does *not* use DNS lookup: I can check that on my machine where I get `xvii` while I don't have any DNS set-up. It appears that it just uses standard reverse lookup, similar to `getent hosts`, and for the `eth0` IP address, `getent hosts 192.168.1.2` gives `xvii`, which agrees with `hostname -A`. But `xvii` is just a short name, not a FQDN.

Comment: @vinc17: run `strace hostname -A` to see what happen.

Comment: @Gnouc Here `strace` gives very little information. It's better to look at the source code. And for `ALL_FQDNS`, I can see that the `getnameinfo` function is used, i.e. standard resolution, which takes `/etc/nsswitch.conf` into account, *not* a direct DNS resolution like with `host` or `dig`.

Comment: @vinc17: Can you give me the source you use? Remember `hostname` in `Redhat/Centos` is different with `Debian`. Try `strace -e trace=connect,sendto,recvfrom,write hostname -A`, you can see it contact your DNS server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16419/discussion-between-vinc17-and-gnouc).